# what is the difference between 'premise' and 'hypothesis' and 'supposition'?

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

I have a question.

what is the difference between ***premise*** and ***hypothesis*** and ***supposition***?

and when to use each of them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Premise: a condition on which a logical argument is based.

Hypothesis:  a plausible conjecture or explanation which can be proved or disproved by experimentation.

Supposition: a belief or notion that might be true or accurate, but might not.  It can turn out to be false or inaccurate.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but please could you edit your answer to contain examples.

Answer (score 4):

To supplement *TRomano*'s response, these are some examples you might consider:

**Premise**: The Earth moves around the Sun [hard fact].

**Hypothesis**: Because the Earth moves around the Sun and because we get days and nights, the Earth also rotates in its path. [Needs experimentation to verify, which makes it a hypothesis. Luckily it was already experimented with way back.]

**Supposition**: The Earth might be absorbed by a dead Sun billions of years into the future [No one knows for sure when, or if it will happen. But we do know the Sun will undergo a supernovae. Whether the Earth will still be around to be absorbed is another story].